# Is it possible to overcome the strong radiational force?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism

If the electro magnetic force is 317 times weaker then the strong force then if 317 electromagnetic fields overlapped an area where the strong force is than couldn't it "turn off" the strong force?

Answer (score 2):

Electromagnetic force is 137 times weaker than the Strong force. The electric charge is a value of how much a particle interact with the electromagnetic field. On the other hand there is the color which is a value of how much a particle, like quarks interact with the strong field. Our world has the property that only colorless free states can exist. As you can see proton is a colorless particle but it has charge $\vert e \vert$ because it consists by two up quarks and one down quark. And if we have two protons together the electric force will be greater than the strong force and they will be repulse its other, unless they come really close so that the quarks of the first proton interact with the quarks of the second.